# Curve a face according to a model

Tags: parent

For one of my project I need to extrude some parts of complex surfaces (ie different curvature on the different axes). What I initially thought was that I could create a vectoriel draving in Illustrator (plane tho) that would fit-ish with my design, then curve them along the "supporting" shape and extrude them.
Unfortunately I didn't find such feature (curve vectoriel drawings) - the curve modifier needing a path, and I couldn t find a way to generate a path reflecting the wished curvature.

For small surfacesn I extrude the svg and apply a boolean modifier to modify locally the vertices of the mesh of the "supporting" shape, then deete the extruded part and extrude the face surounded by the nodes generated thanks to the boolean modifier. But as soon as the form is too big (ie >1/4 of the round piece), this tech does not work anymore...

Many thanks for you help... I m really stuck right now!

Here is the drawing driving my project. I have a model for round part (skull) and I'd like to do the extruded stuffs

[image: skull]

Comment: I think this one really needs an illustration ( even if simplified ) of a particular example of what you would like to do.

Comment: Agree with Robin, this question is very unclear. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72118/advanced-curving-and-linking/72159#72159

Comment: I edited my post with a picture. Sorry for the fuzzy explanation...

Comment: The best method will depend on some other constraints.. is it to be printed? Is it for a game? .. etc

Comment: Ultimately, it will be printed

Comment: Sorry to insist... Is it still not clear?