# How to curve vertices in a vertex group to a bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, edges, vertex-groups

I'm new to blender so please bear with me.

I have a group of vertices I want to fit to a curve. I tried using a simple deform and couldn't quite the results to look like what I wanted. Is there a way to fit the vertices to a bezier curve?

I have tinkered with the curve modifier but it seems like only the topmost point in the vertex group follows the curve and I'm not sure why.

You can see the vertex group highlighted below and the bezier curve is highlighted in the second picture.[image]

[image: vertex curve]

**Update (more informative picture):**
[image]

Comment: Is the Bezier profile the same all the way along  the path?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72118

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm not completely sure what the Bezier profile is but I made sure to align the vertices on the y axis (all points on the curve and in the vertex group share the same y value).

Comment: You show a Bezier in illustration 2. Is that what you want swept along the 'roofline'? Do you want all the other ribs to have the same curve?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I see how this works with separated 3D mesh objects. "Afterwards add the curve objects one by one making sure you align their centers with the mesh object so they match perfectly." I think I am missing this part. Should I be moving the origin of the bezier curve to the origin of the 3D mesh?

Comment: @RobinBetts I want the vertices in the vertex group to fall onto the bezier curve (so I might be using the tool incorrectly). Essentially I need the vertices to "snap" onto the bezier curve - however, I don't really need them to be directly on the curve as long as they mimic the curvature.

Comment: "*Should I be moving the origin of the bezier curve to the origin of the 3D mesh?*" Either that or the other way around, whichever suits you best

Comment: I now understand that I have been misinterpreting how the curve deform tool works on vertex groups - it's not treated as if the vertex groups form a separate mesh, the deform is computed as if applied on the whole mesh but only the selected vertex group is affected. I don't believe the curve deform is what I'm looking for (please correct me if I'm wrong). Are there any suggestions?