# Control a cylinder mesh with multiple curves?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I want to control different parts of a cylinder with curves, so that different parts of the cylinder can have different intersections, controlled by curves, regardless of how the curves are scaled. I found a method using curve modifier on different vertex groups, but it is not very practical.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72118/advanced-curving-and-linking

Comment: you could make this kind of object with nurbs surface and then when you're glad convert to mesh, but I'm not sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *Spline IK* constraint: Create your bezier curves, create one unique armature with bones that follow all around the curves (snap each bone head to each curve vertex), give the constraint to the last bone of the chain (choose *Chain Length* > *number of bones*, here, 4), parent the cylinder to the armature. At the end hook each curve vertex to an empty (or, even better, to the bones of a second armature, it would allow to easily come back to a rest pose).

[image]